# How do I do a reverse proxy for serving static content with a minimal server?

Tags: apache, lighttpd

Thinking of serving up static content with lighttpd and then dynamic content with apache running on a different server.

Comment: Are you asking a specific question, or just pondering?  What have you tried?  What in specific do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

If the question is simply how to proxy only dynamic requests, you could probably use something like the following in your lighttpd config:

```
$HTTP["url"] !~ "^/static" {
    proxy.server  = ( 
        "" => (
            (
                "host" => "10.0.0.2", "port" => 8080 )
            )
        )
}
```

Then, put your static content (images, CSS, Javascript etc) under /static; that way, they'll be served directly by Lighty, while other requests will be proxied to Apache on 10.0.0.2, port 8080 (adjust as appropriate.)